# Creating charts in an HTML file using Dojo operations in a javascript file

Tags: javascript, dojo

So for this project, I have two separate files, one containing some HTML elements, and another containing most of the actions of this application I'm making.  However, in all of the tutorials I can find, creating a chart in a particular spot involves the script being within the HTML document.  For example:

```
<script>
......
var chart1 = new Chart('makeChartHere');
......
</script>
<div id="makeChartHere"><div>
```

This suggests to me that it takes the string used to ID a tag somewhere in the document, and puts a chart there.

In a separate javascript file in the same folder, however, if I try it the same way inside of a method, it doesn't seem to recognize the ID `makeChartHere`, so is there another way to get this ID from a separate file, or am I likely messing up somewhere else and the ID should be seen from the files if they're in the same folder?

I'm pretty new to JavaScript, as well as Dojo, so I'll take any help I can get.

EDIT: 
The problem turned out to be the fault of the interface I'm using, once I changed up the structure of my javascript file it worked fine.  Thanks for all the help yall!

Comment: Do you include your separate javascript file into your html file? Like so: `<script src="yourScript.js"></script>`

Comment: I just added it, but I'm still getting an error.  The interface I have to use for this application doesn't make it easy to figure out what's going wrong, so I could have another issue. Thank you!

Comment: I'm going to retry using dom.byId(id,doc) since it apparently can take the ID and the document name, I'm having a little trouble with the function though so I'll let yall know how it goes

Comment: Is the code initializing your chart inside of the [DOMContentLoaded event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)? Because when you're trying to access your div, it probably doesn't exist yet. Another advice would be to include your script at the end of your html body.

Comment: Thanks! I'll read up on DOMContentLoaded stuff to try and find out how to work with it, but it sounds likely that you're correct with the problem.  I'll update this thread if I can run it.